# Elements of list smaller than some value

Tags: haskell, minimum

I need to calculate the minimum of a list but im trying to do it on this Type declaration
Ord a => a ‐> [a] ‐> [a]
which computes the list of those elements of the given list which are smaller than a
given argument (first argument of the function)

```
mymin :: Ord a => a-> [a] -> [a]

mymin (x:y:xs)   
        | x > y : mymin(y,xs)  
            |otherwise
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so that we can help you out with a specific problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `filter`. It was made for filtering lists:

```
mymin :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
mymin x = filter (< x)
```

Comment: Note to beginners: `(< x)` represents a function created by a so called "operator section", and is equivalent to `(\a -> a < x)`. In other words, it's a partially applied operator.

Answer (score 1):

Note: after re-reading the question it seems you may just want to filter the list as mentioned in the other answers, my answer focuses on your initial requirement to find the minimum element of the list. I'll post it anyway, hopefully someone finds it useful.

---

Your guard syntax is incorrect, but you're almost there with what you've got. Take a look at the section called ["Guards, guards!" in learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). Guards let you include multiple statements like `if a then b`, `if c then d` in a function definition.

You need to include a definition for the `otherwise` case, you've left it off.

In your code you also should line up the `|` chars, the white space is significant and changes how the compiler/interpreter runs your program.

I think I can kind of see where you were going with `mymin(y,xs)` as if you were trying to pass back into your function of type `Ord a => a-> [a] -> [a]`. However as you've got it that won't work. Your current definition, `mymin (x:y:xs)` only matches `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, it's missing a parameter.

If you wanted to pass the smallest value along recursively you'd need to provide a definition like:

```
mymin :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> a
mymin x (y:ys)
```

Extending your work I've come up with the following. It returns the minimum element of the list but is not defined for an empty list (it will error). It's along the same lines as what you've got but keeps the smallest found item in the first index of the list, instead of passing it along as a separate function argument:

```
mymin :: Ord a => [a] -> a
mymin zs = head . mymin' $ zs
  where mymin' (x:[]) = [x]
        mymin' (x:y:xs)
          | x > y = mymin' (y:xs)
          | otherwise = mymin' (x:xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be reading some basic Haskell guides... Still, two hints to get you going with this problem:

- Start with the base case: What's the expected output for an empty list and arbitrary pivot element?
- `mymin` takes two arguments, so the first line of your code should probably be `mymin y (x:xs)`

Edit: On second thought, have you thought about using `filter`?